# What is react JS reusable components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is react JS reusable components? Can anyone please explain this with proper example? Like how do I know its my reusable components and so on. I googled but could not get any proper answer.

Thank You.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html ? A component is a reusable if it has an interface with which it can be configured. That's nothing specific to React though. Consider these functions: `function sayHello() { return 'Hello Felix!'; }` and `function sayHello(name) { return \`Hello ${name}!\`; }`. The second one is reusable (because it accepts an argument as the name), the first one isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example this would be a reusable component, a Button

```
  const Button = ({text, handleClick}) => (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>{text}</button>
  );
```

You can Reuse it with

```
  <Button text="Click me" handleClick={() => console.log("Click")} />
```